# Can the PS Vita AC Adapter be used to charge a DualShock 3?

Tags: ps3, controllers

Can the PS Vita AC Adapter (PCH-ZAC1) be used to charge a DualShock 3 controller? The DS3 requires a "handshake" with the charger to start being charged, but I don't know if the Vita AC Adapter does it.

Comment: I would try this myself, but my Vita AC Adapter is dead sadly.